# read() in a loop with non-blocking socket only reads first 1024 bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, nonblocking

The following code in `socketRead()` is being sent 32K bytes of data. However, only the first 1024 bytes are read. The socket is non-blocking. Am I using `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN` improperly?

I would expect the code in `socketRead()` to keep looping reading the entire 32K bytes instead of stopping after reading only 1024 bytes. ***What am I doing wrong?***

```
    int SetSocketNonBlocking(int socketfd)
    {
            return( fcntl(socketfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(socketfd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK) );
    }


    int SocketReadReady(int sockfd, unsigned int timeoutSeconds)
    {
            fd_set set;
            struct timeval timeout;
            int retCode = 0;

            FD_ZERO(&set);
            FD_SET(sockfd, &set);

            timeout.tv_sec = timeoutSeconds;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;

            while(1)
            {
                    retCode = select(sockfd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
                    if( (retCode == -1) && (errno == EINTR) )
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            break;
                    }
            }
            return( retCode == 1 );
    }



uint8_t *SocketRead(int sockfd, int *bytesRead)
{
        int size_recv = 0;
        int total_size = 0;
        uint8_t *data = NULL;


        // initially we will provide ourselves with a 275k buffer
        // which is more than large enough for a 3" x 8" rasterized image.
        data = malloc((size_t)READ_CHUNK_SIZE * 275);


        if( data != NULL )
        {
                if( SetSocketNonBlocking(sockfd) == -1 )
                {
                        printf("Failed setting non-blocking\n");
                }
                if( SocketReadReady(sockfd, 10) )
                {
                        printf("Socket ready for read\n");
                        do
                        {
                                // TODO: We need to at some point make sure to realloc() the buffer if we have to read more than
                                // 275k of data
                                size_recv =  recv(sockfd, (void *)&data[total_size], READ_CHUNK_SIZE, MSG_DONTWAIT);
                                if( size_recv < 0 )
                                {
                                        if( errno == EWOULDBLOCK )
                                        {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        else if( errno == EAGAIN)
                                        {
                                                continue;
                                        }
                                }
                                else if( size_recv == 0 )
                                {
                                        // connection closed
                                        printf("Connection closed\n");
                                        break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        total_size += size_recv;
                                }
                        }while(1);
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Socket timed out waiting for data to read\n");
                }
        }

        *bytesRead = total_size;
        return data;
}
```

Comment: In `SocketReadReady()`, your `while` loop is unnecessay since it only ever loops 1 time. In `SocketRead()`, `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN` mean the exact same thing (no data available), but you are treating them differently, one `continue`s the loop while the other `break`s the loop. If you are expecting to read the full 32K then they should both `continue` the loop until you have actually received the full 32K. Either way, I would suggest calling `SocketReadReady()` whenever `recv()` reports `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` so that the calling thread is put to sleep until new data actually arrives.

Comment: Thank you. The socketRead() read function actually has no idea how much data is coming. I thought that a non-blocking read/recv returned EWOULDBLOCK if no data was available.. or all data already read. Is this not true?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: "*The socketRead() read function actually has no idea how much data is coming*" - then you will have to `break` your loop on both `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN`, and let the caller decide whether to call `socketRead()` again if it expects more data. "*I thought that a non-blocking read/recv returned EWOULDBLOCK if no data was available*" - it might, or it might report `EAGAIN`. Some 'Nix systems define `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN` as the same value, some don't. Semantically, they should be treated the same way, but you do need to test for them both in case they have different values.

Comment: Also, you are not `break`'ing your loop when `recv()` returns < 0 and `errno` is neither `EWOULDBLOCK` nor `EAGAIN`, indicating a real error occured.  You should also `continue` your loop on `EINTR`, like you do in `SocketReadReady()`

Comment: The meaning of `EWOULDBLOCK` is _"If the socket was blocking.. it would block waiting for data"_, so it represents a scenario in which it is worth to continue reading. As somebody wrote above, you should recv, call select whenever errno is EWOULDBLOCK, and break the loop if recv returned 0 (or -1 with error different from EWOULDBLOCK).

Comment: The select should be inside the read loop. Mindlessly spinning hoping that data has arrived just smokes the CPU.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. I put the select() in the loop and made some other changes. Works great now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you put your comment into the form of an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments. The following code works correctly now. It may need a bit of refinement, but it at least works.

```
uint8_t *SocketRead(int sockfd, int *bytesRead)
{
        int size_recv = 0;
        int total_size = 0;
        uint8_t *data = NULL;
​
​
        // initially we will provide ourselves with a 275k buffer
        // which is more than large enough for a 3" x 8" rasterized image.
        data = malloc((size_t)READ_CHUNK_SIZE * 275);
​
​
        if( data != NULL )
        {
                if( SetSocketNonBlocking(sockfd) == -1 )
                {
                        printf("Failed setting non-blocking\n");
                }
                if( SocketReadReady(sockfd, 10,0) )
                {
                        printf("Socket ready for read\n");
                        do
                        {
                                // TODO: We need to at some point make sure to realloc() the buffer if we have to read more than
                                // 275k of data
                                size_recv =  read(sockfd, (void *)&data[total_size], READ_CHUNK_SIZE);
                                if( size_recv < 0 )
                                {
                                        if( errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR)
                                        {
                                                if( SocketReadReady(sockfd,0,100) )
                                                {
                                                        continue;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                perror("Socket read:");
                                                if( data )
                                                {
                                                        free(data);
                                                        data = NULL;
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                                else if( size_recv == 0 )
                                {
                                        // connection closed
                                        printf("Connection closed\n");
                                        break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        total_size += size_recv;
                                }
                        }while(1);
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Socket timed out waiting for data to read\n");
                }
        }
​
        *bytesRead = total_size;
        return data;
}
```